# Rank for distincted rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, rank

I have this.

| ID | ITEM_ID | ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 | 3 |
| 13 | 4 | 4 |
| 15 | 2 | 5 |
| 16 | 2 | 6 |
| 17 | 3 | 7 |
| 18 | 3 | 8 |

And I need to select to this. Make order for distincted item_id
[image]

Comment: Question: Can the same `ITEM_ID` ever appear in more than one island?  If so, please update your question with such data.

Comment: Just getting the unique item_id and using row_number() from the looks of the post, not 100% it's what you're after. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to order by the minimum `ORDER` for each `item_id` then:

```sql
SELECT item_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN("ORDER")) AS "ORDER"
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY item_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, ITEM_ID, "ORDER") AS
SELECT 10, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 2, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 2, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 3, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 3, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: `ORDER` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier; it would be better to use a different identifier rather than `ORDER`.*

Outputs:

> | ITEM_ID | ORDER |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 4 | 2 |
> | 2 | 3 |
> | 3 | 4 |

---

If you want `item_id` to appear multiple times if there are different `item_id`s between occurrences then, from Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY "ORDER"
  MEASURES
    FIRST(item_id) AS item_id,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS "ORDER"
  PATTERN (same_item+)
  DEFINE same_item AS FIRST(item_id) = item_id
)
```

Which for the sample data above gives the same output; however, if you add some extra rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (id, item_id, "ORDER")
SELECT 19, 1,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 2, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 2, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 4, 12 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output from the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` query is:

> | ITEM_ID | ORDER |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 4 | 2 |
> | 2 | 3 |
> | 3 | 4 |
> | 1 | 5 |
> | 2 | 6 |
> | 4 | 7 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7de55da4c552f025daf0bc26ade12b82)*